# how to run a function multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to find the average of my function running time, out of 1000 runnings. which code should I use to make it run 1000 times and then find the average of them?
my function is:

```
import time

t0 = time.clock()

def binary_search(my_list, x):

    left=0
    right=len(my_list)-1
    while left<=right:
        mid = (left+right)//2
        if my_list[mid]==x:
            return True
        elif my_list[mid] < x: #go to right half
            left = mid+1
        else:              #go to left half
            right = mid-1
    return False  #if we got here the search failed
t1 = time.clock()

print("Running time: ", t1-t0, "sec")
```

Comment: Note that you are **not** executing the function. You are timing the time taken to create the function, which is a completely different (and irrelevant) thing. You should do `t1 = time.clock() binary_search(...) t2 = time.clock()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use a profiler BTW if you don't want to deal with such complexity here's some code:

```
t0 = time.time()

for i in xrange(1000):
    binary_search([1]*1000000,2)

t1 = time.time()
avg = (t1 - t0)/1000

print( "Average Time Taken",avg )
```

Output:

```
('Average Time Taken', 0.007341000080108642)
```

Comment: I'm concerned about the accuracy of this method. If `binary_search` takes only a fraction of a second, then `t1-t0` may be a very rough estimate of the time elapsed. It may be better to put the `t0 =` line before the loop begins, and put the `t1 = ` line after the loop ends. Then you can remove `times`, and calculating `tot` is just `tot = t1 - t0`.

Comment: @stu yes its correct but you might wonder why the time is small and it's because I'm inputting some soft work : `binary_search([4,6,8],4)`

Comment: why did you use ([4,6,8],4)? shouldn't I use ([1]*1000000,2)?

Comment: @stu look now added `binary_search([1]*1000000,2)`

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module for this:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('test()', setup='from __main__ import test')
0.86482962529626661
```

Getting the average result:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('test()', setup='from __main__ import test', number=1000)/1000
8.4928631724778825e-07
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) if it's just a small amount of code. You can select the number of times to repeat the function using the *number* kwarg.

Comment: A conscious reminder that `timeit` defaults, somewhat unexpectedly, to `number=1000000`.  P.S. I'm sorry to the web server I just started sending a million requests to.

Answer (score 1):

Using profiling is probably your best bet. Everything is already coded for you and can give you an accurate report of the matter. Check this out:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Just insert this:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('foo()')
```

Blammo, report done. Furthermore, I personally don't know if I would use timeit. It is meant for very small snippets, and I think you are going to get a more accurate timing using profiling. One way to find out though is to implement BOTH to see the differences. Tell us the results! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have added test_speed() function that will do what you desire if you call it. Just first set some_list and some_values or pass it to the test_speed().

```
  import time

    def test_speed():
      results = []
      for _ in range(10000):
        t0 = time.clock()
        binary_search(some_list, some_value)
        t1 = time.clock()
        results.append(t1-t0)
      return sum(results) / len(results)

    def binary_search(my_list, x):

        left=0
        right=len(my_list)-1
        while left<=right:
            mid = (left+right)//2
            if my_list[mid]==x:
                return True
            elif my_list[mid] < x: #go to right half
                left = mid+1
            else:              #go to left half
                right = mid-1
        return False  #if we got here the search failed
```